# Having trouble reaching end of while statement

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create a game that prompts the user to enter their desired velocity and angle to determine a randomly generated target area. The problem I am having is I can't seem to reach the end of the while statement where it asks the player if they want to play again. I think this is because of the line "continue;" after "guess++;". Is there a work around to allow the user to continue guessing until they get the correct answer AND allow them the option to Play again?

```
        int guess = 1;
        while (guess < 6)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the initial velocity of the cannonball: ");
            double userVelocity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the angle of the cannon (between 0 and 90 degrees): ");
            double userAngle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double targetDistance = distance - golf.Fire(userAngle, userVelocity);

            if (guess <= 5 && targetDistance >= 0.5 || targetDistance <= -0.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Miss! Your shot hit " + golf.Fire(userAngle, userVelocity) + " meters. The target is " + targetDistance + " \n meters away.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                guess++;
                continue;
            }

            if (targetDistance <= 0.5 && targetDistance >= -0.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hit! Congratulations! You hit the target!");
                //continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
            String secondAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            secondAnswer = secondAnswer.Trim();
            String againResponse = secondAnswer.ToLower();

            if (againResponse == "y")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (againResponse == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: for starters use the debugger.. step through the code.. and tell us if you are in a continuous loop or not..or are you getting errors Yes or No..?  show all relevant code.. what is this `golf.Fire(userAngle, userVelocity)`

Comment: @MethodMan I am not getting any errors. I used the debugger and the program never even reaches the "Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?"); line. The method Fire() is in another class. I don't think it really has relevance because the error is in trying to reach the end of the while loop. I mean, I could post it anyway but I don't think it'd be helpful..

Comment: Well, then set a breakpoint on the first line and single-step through the code and you will see where it gets stuck.

Comment: change your loop to this and I think it will work `while (guess <= 6)` also do some reading up on the difference between a `while loop && do While`

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan. I wish I had enough reputation to up-vote your comment or something :+)

Comment: I spotted it like immediately.. no problem @corinne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
while (guess < 6)
```

To be

```
while (guess <=6)
```

When change is 5, `change++` increments it to 6
But, the outer loop condition is true only when change is less then 6. Changing it to less or equal will enter the loop once again and get to the Y/N part

Another note, you probably want to change this line

```
if (guess <= 5 && targetDistance >= 0.5 || targetDistance <= -0.5)
```

To be

```
if (guess <= 5 && ( targetDistance >= 0.5 || targetDistance <= -0.5))
```

Otherwise, your condition would end up being true any time

```
targetDistance <= -0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.

Comment: Ah, I thought about putting parentheses but didn't think it would make a difference; I guess it does! Thanks again.

Comment: your version evaluates like `if ((guess <= 5 && targetDistance >= 0.5) || targetDistance <= -0.5)`. Read [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `For` loops instead of writing `While` statements for any scenario where you're looping a predetermined number of times; this protects you from common mistakes around meeting the loop's stop condition.

Here's an (untested) alternate version.  It's not perfect, but I've made a number of tweaks to help make your code more readable, and less error prone.  I've added comments to explain some of the changes, but please ask if anything doesn't make sense.

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {

        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxGuesses = 5; //putting this in a variable allows you to amend the difficulty
            new Program(maxGuesses);
            Console.WriteLine("Done; press enter to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Kicks off the game
        //On completion asks if the user wants to play again
        //If so relaunches the game; if not exits.
        Program(int maxGuesses)
        {
            bool playAgain = true;
            while (playAgain)
            {
                Play(maxGuesses);
                playAgain = PromptToPlayAgain();
            }
        }

        //returns: 
        //- true if user enters Y
        //- false if user enters N
        //if user enters anything else, keeps asking
        bool PromptToPlayAgain() 
        {
            String againResponse = "";
            while (againResponse != "y" && againResponse != "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
                againResponse = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
            }
            return againResponse == "y";
        }

        double GetVelocity()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the initial velocity of the cannonball: ");
            return double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        double GetAngle()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the angle of the cannon (between 0 and 90 degrees): ");
            return double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //generate a random distance
        //returns a double where 100 <= d < 300
        double GetRangeDistance()
        {
            return randomNumberGenerator.Next(1000, 3000)/10; //returns
        }

        //return true if the person's within .5 meters of the target; else false
        bool CheckWinCondition(double targetDistance)
        {
            return targetDistance <= 0.5 && targetDistance >= -0.5;
        }
        //display message if successful
        void ReportHit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit! Congratulations! You hit the target!");
        }
        //display message if missed
        void ReportMiss(double shotDistance, double targetDistance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Miss! Your shot hit {0} meters. The target is {1} meters away.", shotDistance, targetDistance); //use {n} string formatting to put your numbers into your string
            Console.WriteLine(); //NB: the blank line's the other way round to how you have it in ReportHit
        }
        //the game
        void Play(int maxGuesses)
        {
            Golf golf = new Golf();
            double distance = GetRangeDistance();
            for (int guess = 1; guess <= maxGuesses; guess++) //use a for loop instead of while as we want to iterate a given number of times
            {
                double userVelocity = GetVelocity();
                double userAngle = GetAngle();
                //since we're using different variables for targetDistance and distance I assume 
                //that each shot's being taken from the tee; i.e. the player doesn't move to 
                //where the ball lands.
                //Also I assume all shots go in a straight line between the tee and the hole
                //and that angle is just up/down; not left/right, as otherwise the calc for
                //target distance is off.
                double shotDistance = golf.Fire(userAngle, userVelocity); //store this in a variable so we can reuse the result without recalculating
                double targetDistance = distance - shotDistance;
                if (CheckWinCondition(targetDistance)) 
                {
                    ReportHit();
                    break; //exits the for loop early
                }
                else
                {
                    ReportMiss(targetDistance, shotDistance);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: very nice refactoring